# Reorder factor levels: Specify first level only

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Hi I'm trying to reorder factor levels, by only defining which factor level should be first.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
wrong <-iris %>%  mutate(Species = reorder(Species,desc(Species)))
levels(iris.re$Species)
```

I would like to use mutate to define f.e. `versicolor` to be the first factor level and sort the other factor levels.
I know there are other options to do this, but I would like to use `plyr`/`dplyr`.

Thanks

Comment: relevel() was what I needed!! Thanks, StupidWolf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try relevel:

```
iris <- iris %>%  mutate(Species=relevel(Species,ref="versicolor"))
```